# Confused! Two tailed t-test in r with equal variance

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, ecology

I am a complete novice in this but just trying to have a go. I have a dataset which has the number of birds in my garden each day for one month in June 2020 and June 2021. I would like to see if there is a significant difference in my total. As far as I can work out, a two-tailed t-test with equal variances would work for this (however, please correct me if I'm wrong).

H0: there is no significant difference between the number of birds visiting my garden in June 2020 and June 2021.

Please could someone help to write the code for this in `R`?

[image: See photo for data]

Comment: I'm _think_ that that test in Excel is a test of equal variances, not a test of equal means (like what people usually think of two sample *t*-test).

Comment: But it sounds like you are looking for a test of means, or a test for another location measure.  It's not clear what you have in mind when you say "difference in my total".

Answer (score 2):

In `R` you can simply do (thanks @COOLSerdash for the remark!)

```
t.test(Jun20, Jun21, var.equal = TRUE)
```

but there is a fundamental problem with this approach. Your variables are counts and, for the worse, with quite small numbers. They surely violate the normality assumption behind the `t.test`.

I would suggest going with a two-sample Poisson (or even better, a negative binomial) test in which you assume the two variables are independently Poisson-distributed with different parameter values.

Comment: The default in `t.test` is to do an unequal (Welch) $t$-test though. The option `var.equal = FALSE` needs to be added to get the $t$-test with equal variances.

Comment: @COOLSerdash , that is, `var.equal = TRUE` for equal variances.

Comment: @SalMangiafico That's right, my bad.